# visibility of the static private variable in it's class php

Tags: php, variables, scope, static, private-members

I have the following code:

```
myClass extends Class{

    private static $var1 = 0;

    public function index(){
        if(some condition){
            $this->var1 = 1;
        }
    }

    public function success(){
        if($this->var1 == 0){
            ...
        }else{
            ...
        }
    }

}
?>
```

My problem is that I cannot access the var1 from the functions in the class. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: because `this` is not `self`

Comment: Read about [static properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties) in PHP OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables (and methods) are accessed using the `::` operator. To access `$var1` within the class, use the following code instead:

```
myClass extends Class{

private static $var1 = 0;

public function index(){

    if(some condition){
        static::$var1 = 1;
   }
}

public function success(){
    if(static::$var1 == 0){
     ...
    }else{
     ...
    }
} 

}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's clear now. Combination of 'private static' was a bit confusing ...